# Is there a bash command to make a screen text box?

Tags: macos, bash, software-recommendation

I am writing a small application for Intel OS X to display a range of internal temperatures but I have not been able to find a satisfactory text box command/application. Applescript works but the box has a mind of its own - only one width (which is too wide), goes where it wants and insist upon being on top. A Terminal window is best but tedious to make entirely risk free.

I am looking for a free of charge text window, preferably generated by a pre-compiled bash command, with a narrow border and without buttons, decoration, title bar, scroll bar etc. It should be manually and programmatically resizable or auto-fit the text. It should be possible to both manually and programmatically position it anywhere.

It must be small and self-contained so that it can be put inside an application and not limited to being installed on a particular OS/computer. Preferably it should work on all Intel OS X Mac computers.

Code for Applescript solution:

```
#!/usr/bin/osascript
tell application "System Events" to set d to POSIX path of container of (path to me)
set k to "Open"
repeat until (k = "Close")
tell me to activate
set k to button returned of (display dialog (do shell script "s=" & d & "/c; b=''; 
g(){ x=$($s -k $1 -r); y=${x: -6:2}; z=${x: -3:2}; w=0; [ $z = 80 ] && w=5; b=$b\"  $((16#$y)).$w   $2\n\"; }; 
g TA0P 'Ambient'; 
g TC0C 'CPU A Core 0'; 
g TC2C 'CPU B Core 0'; 
g TCAH 'CPU A HeatSink'; 
g TCBH 'CPU B HeatSink'; 
g TH0P 'Drive Bay 0'; 
g TH1P 'Drive Bay 1'; 
g TH2P 'Drive Bay 2'; 
g TH3P 'Drive Bay 3'; 
g TN0H 'MCH HeatSink'; 
g Tp0C 'PSU1 Inlet'; 
g Tp1C 'PSU1 Component'; 
echo \"$b\"") buttons {"Close"} default button 1 with title "Temperature (Centigrade)" giving up after 19.9)
end repeat
```

Code for Terminal solution:

```
#!/usr/bin/osascript
tell application "System Events" to set d to POSIX path of container of (path to me)
tell application "Terminal"
activate
set T to do script "#"
set W to id of window 1 whose tab 1 = T
close (every window whose id ≠ W)
set bounds of window id W to {2, 25, 202, 310}
end tell
repeat
do shell script "s=" & d & "/c; 
b=\" Temperature (Centigrade)\n\n $(date \"+%y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S\")\n\n\"; 
g(){ x=$($s -k $1 -r); y=${x: -6:2}; z=${x: -3:2}; w=0; [ $z = 80 ] && w=5; b=\"$b $((16#$y)).$w   $2\n\"; }; 
g TA0P 'Ambient'; 
g TC0C 'CPU A Core 0'; 
g TC2C 'CPU B Core 0'; 
g TCAH 'CPU A HeatSink'; 
g TCBH 'CPU B HeatSink'; 
g TH0P 'Drive Bay 0'; 
g TH1P 'Drive Bay 1'; 
g TH2P 'Drive Bay 2'; 
g TH3P 'Drive Bay 3'; 
g TN0H 'MCH HeatSink'; 
g Tp0C 'PSU1 Inlet'; 
g Tp1C 'PSU1 Component'; echo \"$b\" > /tmp/TidC"
tell application "Terminal" to do script "PS1=''; printf '\\33c\\e[3J'; cat /tmp/TidC; echo -n ' '; for q in {9..1}; do echo -n $q' '; sleep 1; done" in window id W
delay 9.6
end repeat
```

Comment: By text box you mean window? Can you add the AppleScript code you are using currently?

Comment: I like [terminal-notifier for alerts](https://github.com/julienXX/terminal-notifier). Do you need a more general purpose toolkit? Syntax gets more complicated for larger design toolkits…

Comment: There is also [Pashua](https://github.com/BlueM/Pashua), but since you are already using AppleScript, it has access to the Cocoa frameworks via AppleScriptObjC.

Comment: Alerts and dialogs are normally modal and hence are not compatible with my requirements. I need something which is happy to continue working in a continuous loop behind other windows. Although my family have some of the latest Macs I often use Mac Pros 1,1 and1,3. These use OS X 10.7 and 10.8. I would prefer to have solutions which work with OS X 10.6 onwards. Neither of the above appear to work with my Macs. I would also prefer not to use Terminal as some less experienced users don't trust it.

Comment: Yup, you now have a full blown software development problem. I’ll answer the “no” since you’re not missing any easy wins. Now you will have to choose a tech stack or hire a developer / consultant to assist with scoping this project if that skill is outside your wheelhouse currently.

Comment: What path did you ultimately take to achieving what you wanted?

Answer (score 1):

No general screen box creating toolset ships with macOS. Bash does not operate outside the command line interface and isn’t suitable for writing a full on macOS app that runs continually.

You can of course launch other programs that use the display GUI interface like AppleScript, [Pashua](https://github.com/BlueM/Pashua), or [terminal-notifier](https://github.com/julienXX/terminal-notifier).

Perhaps an existing tool like https://bjango.com/mac/istatmenus/ or the venerable [SMCFanControl](https://www.eidac.de/?cat=40) could do what you seek rather than crafting a bash launched custom tool?

For command-line GUI you may prefer a tool like [ncurses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ncurses) which will simplify the amount of macOS GUI concepts you have to learn unless you’re interested in macOS specific options.

From the excellent comments on your question, you really want a proper macOS app and not just a quick bash tool to pop up one (potentially modal) dialog.

The best free option that comes to mind is Xcode and SwiftUI since it does charts and more now for free.

Comment: Perhaps I did not make it clear that I don't want to use Applescript or Terminal. I would like a very small piece of code which will work on Intel OS X computers from OS X 6 until the most recent. Before I get involved in a project I would like to ensure that I will not be reinventing the wheel. Perhaps this is not the best forum for my question.

Comment: Yup, you now have a full blown software development problem. I’ll answer the “no” since you’re not missing any easy wins. Now you will have to choose a tech stack or hire a developer / consultant to assist with scoping this project. We cover scripting in scope here. Maybe https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ if you’re diy. Not sure where to hire a developer / consultant to assist your efforts if that’s your path @NevilleHillyer it’s fine to leave the question up here,  others may have answers to add that solve exactly your need.

Comment: As regards reinventing the wheel - [SMCFanControl](https://www.eidac.de/?cat=40) does something similar for older OSes [I think it's freeware]. For newer OSes, [iStatMenus](https://bjango.com/mac/istatmenus/) has take the mantle [paid]. The upside is they're already prepped to know which sensors are available with each Mac. That changes a lot over different models.

Comment: I take your point about SMCFanControl but as far as I can tell there is no one solution for the full range of OSs required. I have used the original smc-0.01 for many years and have several pieces of software embedding it. Pity it appears to no longer be available. I am unsure how to progress my request as more general and unrelated to temperature - I often have need of such a window. Widgets get close but appear tied to a narrow range of OSs and even these can be bloated.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my attempt using `wish`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env wish 

pack [text .t]
update idletasks

while {[gets stdin line] >= 0} {
    # puts ">>> '$line'"
    .t insert end "$line\n"
    update idletasks
}
```

This makes a text widget, puts it in the app window, then reads stdin and adds it to the end of the text.

Test it with

```
while sleep 2; do date; done | wish tbox.wish
```

There's many options to set the width, height, color. Can even remove the standard window borders, too (I think).

As far as I know, all the old OS X releases had Tcl and Tk installed (`wish` is the shell for Tcl/Tk, while `tclsh` is Tcl only).  It dates back to the early 1990's but it's still very useful.